# c# dataGridView null reference exception

Tags: c#, datagridview, nullreferenceexception

I'm using this code:

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("Title");
dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
```

to populate my `dataGridView` but I get a `null reference exception` when I set the `datasource`.

Comment: Where are you initializing dataGridView1?

Comment: @ComanderKai77 Where does `dataGridView1` comes from ?

Comment: In your code only if `dataGridView1` is `null`, such Exception will be thrown. Check that or give us more code.Notice that Exception always contains number of the line which thrown exception.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: The DGV is created by the Forms

Comment: The problem was, the code from above gets executed before the form is loaded.

Answer (score 4):

Your dataGridView1 is most likely a NULL reference. To verify, set a breakpoint on the line and when you hit it, hover your mouse over dataGridView1.